# Arrows on small circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw arrows on small circles. The "decorate" method works well on large ones but the following

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,
    decoration={markings, 
      mark= at position 0.75 with {\arrow{Stealth[width=2pt,length=3pt]}}}]
    \foreach \t in {0,...,7} {
      \draw[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) circle ({\t/5});
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image: arrows on circles]

which isn't so nice when the circles get small. I guess I'd like to either translate or rotate the arrows. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: [Output from MetaPost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnh1G.png) if that is an option. (Probably also possible in tikz, but I do not know how it works...)

Comment: Please post compilable code, so people trying to help does not need to figure out what packages and other stuff you are using.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \t in {1,...,7}
\draw[thick, -{Stealth[width=3pt, length=4pt, red]}] (-180:\t/5) arc[start angle=-180, delta angle=450, radius={\t/5}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Concentric circles with arrows]

Edit: Here it is with the `bend` option as suggested. Note that will deform the arrow head itself.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \t in {1,...,7}
\draw[thick, -{Stealth[width=3pt, length=4pt, red, bend]}] (-180:\t/5) arc[start angle=-180, delta angle=450, radius={\t/5}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might also consider the `bend` option: `Stealth[width=3pt, length=4pt, bend]`

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \foreach \r in {.4,.6,...,1.1}{
            \draw[-stealth,line width=3pt] (0:\r) arc(0:270:\r) ;
            \draw[line width=3pt] (270:\r) arc(270:360:\r);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```